# Html - insert html into <p> </p> tags

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have a text :

```
<p> hello world! </p>
```

and I am using a function that cut the text after 5 words and adds " ...show more"

I want the result to be like this :

> hello ... show more

Because of the `<p>` tags what I get is this output :

> hello ...show more

what I see when I inspect the element is this :

```
<p> hello </p> ...show more
```

I must mention that the text can be with `<p>` or without.

Is there a way to solve this problem ? 
Is there a way to insert the added text inside the `<p>` tag ? 
I need to mention that I need the `<p>` tags, I can't use strip tags function.

Thanks, 
Yami

Comment: How are you inserting the text? Javascript?

Comment: and how do you want to do this? PHP function, javascript, jquery, something? You have to write better questions to get better answers

Comment: what does PHP have to do with your question?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this?

```
var text = "<p>hello world</p>";
var res = "<p>" + text.substring(3, 8) + " ...show more</p>";
```

It results in:

```
<p>hello ...show more</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it, you have two options:

- `.split()` the string by spaces (assuming a space separates words) then slice the first (up to) 5 elements. If there are greater than 5 element, add "...read more"; if not, it's unnecessary.
- You can use some regex replace and (with a negative lookahead) ignore the first 5 words, but replace all other text with your "...read more". *(I personally find this one having more overhead, but you could probably use `(?!(?:[^\b]+?[\b\s]+?){5})(.*)$` as a pattern)*

Having said that, here's what i mean with a string split:

```
function readMore(el){
    var ary = el.innerHTML.split(' ');
    el.innerHTML = (ary.length > 5 ? ary.slice(0,5).join(' ') + '... read more' : ary.join(' '));
}

var p = document.getElementById('foo');
readMore(p);
```

Assuming of course, for the purposes of this demo, `<p id="foo">Hello, world! How are you today?</p>` (which would result in `<p id="foo">Hello, world! How are you...read more</p>`)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('p').text($('p').text().replace('world!', '... show more'));
```

Comment: Is this humour or a very bad answer? ;-)

Comment: @Capsule - if something is wrong, point it out please ... wud help everyone to learn from mistakes ...

Comment: I guess it's not humor then ;-) Your method is specific to this example, it's not universal. Do you really think the text to replace will always be "Hello world!"?

Comment: @Capsule : intension was to be specific ... but point noted ... will take care in future .... thanks ...